# extjs 3.4 ComboBox send wrong data type

Tags: parsing, extjs, combobox, extjs3

this is the problem.

I have a store in which I have a fiels without typization named al_key
The al_key actually comes as an int from the server

```
{ al_key: 5512, description: "test"}
```

I load those data into a gridpanel, then I edit the Record with a Form that takes the Record from the row. In the form I have a combobox named "AL VALUE" preselected with the al_key key.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    store: 'AlStore',
    forceSelection: true,
    allowBlank: true,
    editable: false,
    fieldLabel: 'AL VALUE',
    name: 'al_key',
    hiddenName: 'al_key',
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'id',
    disabled: true
}
```

Now, the problem is: when I load the Record (getForm().loadRecord(rec)) the field al_key is a number and when I submit the form it sends a number.
When I change the value of the combo the fiel al_key becomes a STRING and it sends a STRING!

How can I force to use integer?

Thank you Al.

Comment: Can we see the complete store (AlStore) definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
THe problem is that the FORM doesn't know about the store configuration and it passes all data as a normal form.
So, if I fill the store in this way: 
`this.page.dataGrid.store.recordType(this.getForm().getValues()));` 
it will insert all strings. 
Here is my workaround..

```
MyRecordType  = Ext.data.Record.create(this.page.dataGrid.store.fields.keys);
var myRec = new MyRecordType();
this.getForm().updateRecord(myRec);
this.page.dataGrid.store.add(myRec);
this.page.dataGrid.store.save();
```

tnx!!
A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry...
It seems a problem of the FormPanel.
When I call : `this.page.dataGrid.store.insert(0, new this.page.dataGrid.store.recordType(this.getForm().getValues()));`
the `this.getForm().getValues()` returns this object: 
`al_key: "4088"
cod_aerom: "1458"`

WHY??!